# rare + remarkable | -- something that means rare + remarkable

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, phrase-requests

**update**: at the point of update, im going to focus on specific examples, and not on generalistic words, to show the meaning, but in cases where i may want to succinctly express something being rare & remarkable, it would still be nice that there exist one clean word to express both these meanings. it appears thus far to be a word that needs to be created in the 21th century, if it hasn't already been (which i'd still be shocked and very very surprised about)

there's plenty of reasons why it's important to have this solution long-term, but when the question was asked, i was just trying to 'find-replace' all my 'rare & remarkable' usage within my massive notes on onenote

---

**original post**

since finding words for specific meanings *almost always* tends to be extremely, extremely hard, feel free to suggest a creative/created/made-up word (or anything that would work). free free to say anything in comments as well

---

im pretty sure there's not a word in the entire conventional english vocab for what im looking for

**rare** = a significantly lower proportion of something/anything/things, as in:

> people that do amazing things are rare (like the ~1% of them), while the rest are pretty common (the 99%), and this is shown in many many things, such as in concepts like the long-tail -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail

**remarkable** = close to meaning to amazing; beyond exceptional, as in:

> saying that a person or action, etc. is remarkable does not directly tell others that said person is also incredibly rare in society, even though the meaning should be implicit and obvious

---

note: don't want to use something i feel is incredibly clumsy like 'remarkably rare' -- hate adverbs. it's such a.... ah.. how do i put this... such a low and primitive workaround due to the high limits of language

Comment: You mean "remarkably rare"?

Comment: Please see http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=Rare%20remarkable which has hundreds of options.

Comment: the closest thing that stuck out initially to me was 'extraordinary' though already thought of this, and 'rare' is a stronger word. 'extraordinary' is closer in meaning to remarkable, and loses a lot of the potency that rare expresses. 'novel' is a nice word close to 'a refreshing kind of new', i think i'll like to hear the creative solutions of others. would be interesting. maybe using a commonly well-known example would be the best course of action?

Comment: If the word "unique" were not used so frequently and so incorrectly, I'd say "unique" is the word you're looking forward. Unfortunately, however, it is. Without thinking, people today say "very unique." Oh well.

Comment: i personally don't see the word unique too often, though not sure what kind of materials you read. 'very unique' is grammatically correct but doesn't make perfect sense, semantically, as in meaning. unique does not imply 'remarkable' or synonymous, as in 'what a unique apple. i've never seen a purple apple before!', though this does not necessarily indicate that the apple was in fact 'remarkable' - it didn't give 100x nutritional benefits or taste any better. it was 'merely unique'. i use 'special' and 'one of a kind' (moreso) over unique to try to make the meaning clearer, but...

Comment: why not just use "extraordinary"?

Comment: i mentioned a key reason above: "'extraordinary' is closer in meaning to remarkable, and loses a lot of the potency that rare expresses." but to expand on other niche reasons: 1) when you're talking about things that are rare & remarkable, you want to use a word that's at least not too common, you obviously don't want to be using a word that's pretty basic and common to describe such rare things, especially when it's already lacking precision when compared to rare & remarkable. 2) length-wise, about the same, so nothing necessarily better there, 3) ...actually i'll go put an update on the OP

Comment: If it wasn't rare, it wouldn't be extraordinary.

Comment: if it wasn't rare, it could be merely be common, or be at 30% (how common is that? pretty common for most things). 3) extraordinary also uses the base of 'ordinary'. you want to be using a word that is its own when describing things that truly rare & remarkable, you don't want to start from the low, and then just attach 'extra' to it and now somehow, it is special

Comment: You put in a lot of work disagreeing with suggestions by the community here. You could save some time by showing more of your own research and rationale for what words you find unacceptable and more precision on what you would find acceptable.

Comment: i'll just explain a few key things along the way instead of writing 100 essays of the bat, not sure what info all kinds of different people with different understandings would need to know, and would likely be boring to some, anyway you actually got it, see your answer. because words are used practically (to communicate and such), it's also important the words make practical sense. if say ~80% of those with pieces of paper from universities don't understand what a word means, should that word actually be used? for my goals, no

Comment: One of the requirements for a single-word-request is an example sentence showing how the word will be used; since you want to "find & replace" instances of *rare and remarkable*, it should be easy to add an example (or two or three—more context is better!) taken directly from your existing corpus. Just replace the instances of *rare and remarkable* with ___ (or even just bold the words you want to replace). That will help people get a better handle on exactly how you want to use this word.

Comment: the context is my memory and everything that i know. i tend to use the phrase **rare & remarkable** as section headers/breaks, or simply as a reminder to myself about what im looking for -- it's use in all contexts. context matters for 'flexible words' (multi-discrete meanings) as in one of the answers, or for more specific/refined words, but these are highly general words so the context does not actually matter in these cases.

Comment: generally these words are to describe all things that fits its classification, so of course you would use words/things that have encompassing-type meaning but that still have very clear boundaries (aka: not words that have multiple discrete meanings). this is obvious and presumed when we are talking about highly general words.

Comment: i'll be interested in an example (or a link/article/video on the Web) where context actually matters specifically for a one-for-one (non-flexible), highly general word with clear boundaries on its meaning. 'unique' is context-neutral. in my usage, and in dictionaries, it means 'one-of-a-kind'. it's a one for one (consistent) word and there shouldn't be any confusion from anyone about this in all and every single context in this universe. it's a universal word with universal meaning -- until a large populous starts using it differently, in which case, the meaning then intrinsically changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains a word that seems to satisfy your requirements: ***exceptional***:

> 1. Unusual; not typical.
>      ‘*late claims will only be accepted in exceptional circumstances*’
>
>    1.1 Unusually good; outstanding.
>      ‘*a child of exceptional ability*’
>
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exceptional)</sub>

Comment: yea you came closest, the other one would've been 'special' - but this word has been very commericalised as in 'special edition' or 'special needs', both of which, in these usage, does not express something being 'remarkable' just 'rare in a pretentious kinda way that's not really special' -- the 2nd usage can also imply a sense of inferiority. ** though given how many people couldn't get it right, it makes you wonder if they actually understand what 'exceptional' means, so would it be better to directly express both meanings in the form of 'rare' & 'remarkable' to help them understand better?

Comment: for my 'find-replace' on my onenote, i decided to go with '1%' -- the other option was '#1', but that designates 1 thing, and im talking about plurally/generally about the 'rare & remarkable'. 1% means rare, and in many contexts, it also means the remarkable. this likely gives me the most precision in meaning -- when lacking in examples. the update i had put on the OP about not focusing on incredibly generalistic words does cover the core problem though. do people actually understand how extremely extremely rare 'exceptional' implies? for most, i don't think the 99% (majority) do understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities. I'll name one: **Recherché**.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recherche)  defines it as

> very rare; eximious

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recherche) defines it as

> very unusual, not generally known about, and chosen with great care in order to make people admire your knowledge or style (hence, remarkable)

Comment: hmm.. interesting one. looks like there's a couple of discrete meanings for this word in various dictionaries, and shows that it's been used historically to mean either 'rare' or 'exquisite' or meanings associated with connoisseurs. so basically it's a flexible word in how it can be used. but it's a 'either-or' kind of word, and doesn't do the job of combining both meanings of rare & remarkable into one

Comment: Probably no word, as you said.  "One of a kind" might work.  Sui generis.